# SVD compression of image does not give satisfactory result

Tags: image, matlab, compression

let us suppose we  have following image
[image]

i have read it and converted to gray scale in matlab

```
I=imread('tbilisi.jpg');
gray=rgb2gray(I);
```

and i have following result
[image]

now i have done  svd of this image(of course  first i have converted to double format)

```
>> [U E V]=svd(double(gray));
```

let us show sizes  of every component we have got

```
>> whos
  Name         Size                  Bytes  Class     Attributes

  E          575x1000              4600000  double              
  I          575x1000x3            1725000  uint8               
  U          575x575               2645000  double              
  V         1000x1000              8000000  double              
  gray       575x1000               575000  uint8
```

now let us choose first  40 component  and  approximate original image

```
>> approximated=uint8(U(:,1:40)*E(1:40,1:40)*V(:,1:40)');
```

and show result
[image]

now let us check again  sizes

```
>> whos
  Name                 Size                  Bytes  Class     Attributes

  E                  575x1000              4600000  double              
  I                  575x1000x3            1725000  uint8               
  U                  575x575               2645000  double              
  V                 1000x1000              8000000  double              
  approximated       575x1000               575000  uint8               
  gray               575x1000               575000  uint8
```

approximated and gray have same  bytes,  where is compression? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

A compressed image is an image that is encoded. The SVD components are the ones you are supposed to store. For example,

```
compressed = {U(:,1:40), E(1:40,1:40), V(:,1:40)'}
```

could be your compressed image. `compressed` would have less information than `gray` (though all values are doubles here, so each value takes up 8 times as much space than one input image pixel; converting to single-precision floats would help, for example).

When you multiply the components together to form `approximated`, you are decoding ("decompressing") the image. The result is necessarily the same number of pixels as the `grey` image, and therefore occupies exactly the same amount of space.

Note that this type of compression is typically done by dividing the image up into small squares. Each square is compressed independently, and the number of components stored are chosen such that the difference with the input is not too large. This allows parts of the image with little detail to be represented with fewer bytes than those with lots of detail.

Comment: sorry  what i am doing incorrectly?how can i fix   ?what should i add

Comment: The "compressed image" would be a file containing the selected components of `U`, `E` and `V`. When you multiply those together to form an image you can display, you are decoding ("decompressing") the image. You're not doing anything wrong per se, you just misunderstand what a "compressed image" is. If it's compressed you cannot display it, you need to decode for display. Once you decode you have as many pixels as the input, of course those take up as much space as the input.

Comment: to generally idea is that compressed file should have small amount of byte right? if  when i am decoding , i am getting image with same size, than compression  where is

Comment: @datodatuashvili: I've edited the answer to clarify these things. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: decoded image has  same number of  byte as original right?  then what is sense of  SVD i did not understand really

Comment: wait  i am  not multiplying together?

Comment: `compressed` (in my answer) is supposed to have fewer bytes than `gray`. That's the purpose of the SVD. Indeed, you're not multiplying those elements together *yet*. This is where you have fewer bytes.

Comment: but when i will multiply, i will get approximated image right?  does not it should take also few byte? because instead of all singular values, i took only 40

Comment: i am really confused  now

Comment: could you please explain me  how compression are done using svd

Comment: Read my post again, look at all the intermediate values, think about how much space they occupy. Think about it some more. If you still don't understand it, open a book about image compression. I can't explain it any clearer than what I've written here. Sorry.

Comment: does not approximated image =compressed image?

Comment: No, it's the decoded (decompressed) image, as I wrote earlier. Please pick up a book (or an online tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion in terminology here:  Approximated image != compressed image.

The original (gray) and decoded (approximate) image should be the as similar as possible--including size.

The compressed "image" is NOT an image. It is the set of bytes that you store in a file and send to your friends. In this case it's the truncated  U, E and V matrices, which is hopefully smaller than the decoded image. When your friend gets the compressed file, she can then create the decoded image.

Comment: ok,  s i understood decoding happens to the  singular matrices right?   then what is the role of selecting  subset of singular values?

Comment: Selecting the subset is the compression step.

Comment: how can i compress  U E and V matrices?